# Web Development Frameworks: Zend Framework vs Ruby on Rails vs ASP.NET MVC

Tags: frameworks

I've used Zend Framework before but would like to know how you think it compares to other MVC frameworks? Which is better and why?

**Zend Framework** my background with this is ~3 mths

Good:

- Templating thru Zend_Layouts & Zend_Views
- Zend_Forms, Zend_Validation, Zend_Filter: assists in form inputs
- Zend_Tool now allows for something like Ruby on Rails's CMD code genration except that its now still very limited in terms of functionality

Bad:

- steep learning curve
- can be confusing for me now still

**Ruby on Rails** viewed some screencasts only

Good

- i like the cmd code generation for controller, actions, models and forms
- it seems to be easily incorporated with AJAX

Bad

- i get the impression that it will be hard to deploy

**ASP.NET MVC** also watched a few screencasts only

Good

- i like LINQ
- extensive support with VS 2010 will speed up development

Bad

- expensive

Comment: Just thought it's worth mentioning that ASP.NET MVC is free. If you're talking about the licensing fees of Windows, you can run ASP.NET MVC it on any platform that Mono 2.4 supports (Linux/Mac/Windows) for no cost.

http://mono-project.com/Main_Page

Comment: "better" and "objective" don't work well together ;)

Comment: This question is screaming for an edit. *curses his lack of rep*

Comment: you should also check out django (python)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Zend Framework:**

Good:
Stable API, acceptable performance, doesn't get in the way when it's not needed, easy to integrate legacy databases

Bad:
Hard to get into, sometimes confusing syntax

And also the general php advantages apply, such as easy deployment, portability, large ecosystem

**Rails**

Good: 
Easy to create a working app, easy deployment with phusion passenger, nice unit testing integration

Bad:
Performance not always great, API is always changing, hard to break out of the framework

**General**

Rails is helpful to create an application very quick. It definately takes longer with the Zend Framework. But only as long as no problems arise. I feel that it's way harder to detect the root of a problem in rails. All the magic happening everywhere in rails is very nice in many cases but it makes the behaviour of the whole application less predictable. So if you don't want to follow the extact path, the framework creators have thought out for you, you'll likely run into serious problems with rails. You probably have to write a third less code with rails, but that costs you a third of your control over your application.

But the biggest annoyance for me was that rails changes very much between versions. I've spent a lot of time porting applications to newer rails versions, with deprecations and api changes here and functionality externalized to plugins there. It seems that rails isn't that mature as it's said to be.

Answer (score 0):

I personally love Ruby - it's a great language to code in. I also write C#.NET for my proper job and think the MVC framework is the best thing to happen to .NET since it launched. However, for maximum portability I still use PHP for my own web projects as it's really easy to find cheap hosting on Linux (and it works on IIS too).

Answer (score 0):

I would add to the list [CakePHP](http://www.cakephp.org). It's really a "Rails on PHP", with strict convention over configuration and strict MVC. I personally prefer CakePHP to Zend. Oh, and deployment is really really easy.

Answer (score 0):

I develop mostly in php and ruby and I think there are pros and cons of both.

I think most of us agree, Zend takes a little longer to spin up a new app.  The lack of command line tools and scaffolding make the process a little less expedited.  But I feel the performance is better, a lot better actually.

Ruby/Rails spins up super fast and thanks to scaffolding, you can get a working skeleton extremely quick.  Performance could be better though and I think Zend dominates Rails in this category.  The language is fun as hell but as others have mentioned, there is way to much magic.  If you find magic methods annoying in php, your going to hate the concept of ruby, where various code blocks or gems reopen base classes and create magic that has you scratching your head and thinking, "where the hell did this come from?". Also, as others have mentioned, unless you never update your application, be prepared for migrations.  Rails 3.2 all the way to the latest version, 5.0.2, I think, will have you refactoring code for a while.

If I'm developing an app that I plan to work with long term, I usually go with Zend.  If I need to spin it up fast and performace/load isn't much of a major factor, I go with rails.

I don't know if I've added any more insight then the other posters but these are my personal preference.